# MYSQL - TRANSAÇÕES

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, mysql, transações

Boa noite, sou iniciante em mysql e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida.
Quando faço uma transação como essa

```
   START TRANSACTION ;
        INSERT INTO PESSOA2(IDPESSOA,NOME) VALUES(NULL,'PEDRO2');
        INSERT INTO DEPENDENTES(IDDEP,NOME,IDPESSOA) VALUES(NULL,'CAROL',543);
        INSERT INTO DEPENDENTES(IDDEP,NOME,IDPESSOA) VALUES(NULL,'CAROL',1);
COMMIT;
```

é uma transação de teste, nada especifico ....

Coloquei pra dar error na segunda linha propositalmente... mas quando o error acontece,não insere nada na tabela dependentes(mesmo o segundo insert na tabela estando correto) ,mas   ainda assim insere na tabela pessoa2, porque? estou fazendo algo de errado?!Não era tudo ou nada?!

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

---

Boa noite Ricardo, agradeço a atenção . Então, estou bem confuso quanto a isso... se eu faço a seguinte transação em uma única tabela, ao encontrar o error, independente se tiver alguma linha correta, ela não insere...Ai me vem a dúvida, quando o insert for em uma única tabela, ao encontrar error não insere mesmo contendo outras linhas que estão corretas?!

```
START TRANSACTION ;
```

INSERT INTO DEPENDENTES VALUES(NULL,'PEDRO',213);
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES (NULL,'CARLOS',1);
COMMIT;

Continuando... Mesmo sem o handler, ao encontrar o error não era pra simplesmente parar ali?!

Nunca havia visto o handler , fui testar o código que você mandou esta dando error... "DECLARE IS NOT VALID AT THIS POSITION ..." Pode me ajudar? Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

*"Coloquei pra dar error na segunda linha propositalmente"* , isso vai fazer com que falhe somente essa linha, até esse ponto.

*"mas ainda assim insere na tabela pessoa2, porque?"*  porque a primeira linha não deu erro. Precisa compreender melhor antes o conceito de transação.

A ideia é fazer várias operações de forma atômica, ou seja, como se fossem uma só.
No seu exemplo, tem três comandos, uma vez que foi aberta uma transação, todos os comandos a seguir do `START TRANSACTION` serão tratados como uma única transação. O erro ai no seu código é, se deu erro, deveria fazer `ROLLBACK` e não `COMMIT`. Até o momento do `COMMIT` nada foi "transacionado" em definitivo no banco, esse o propósito da *transacation*, garantir que nada vai ser definitivo, até encontrar um COMMIT.

Nesse caso, deveria verificar se todos os comandos foram executados sem erros, e ai sim fazer `COMMIT`, e caso contrário `ROLLBACK`.

Para fazer, seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  -- cria um "handler" para tratar a transaction
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  -- se acontecer algum erro, o handler vai fazer rollback
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;  -- inicia a transaction
        INSERT INTO PESSOA2(IDPESSOA,NOME) VALUES(NULL,'PEDRO2');
        INSERT INTO DEPENDENTES(IDDEP,NOME,IDPESSOA) VALUES(NULL,'CAROL',543);
        INSERT INTO DEPENDENTES(IDDEP,NOME,IDPESSOA) VALUES(NULL,'CAROL',1);
    COMMIT;  -- se chegou até aqui, o handler não pegou erro, então faz commit
```

**EDIT** o *statement* `EXIT HANDLER` é usando dentro de *stored procedures*, se estiver só executando os comandos como script isso não pode ser usando.

Nesse caso, deve analisar o resultado e a seguir decidir se fará `COMMIT` ou `ROLLBACK` manualmente. Para isso:

- Remova o `COMMIT`;
- O `mysql` vai fazer `COMMIT` por padrão ao final, para evitar isso, inicie o script com `SET autocommit = OFF`, e faça isso manualmente ao final;
- Execute o código com `START TRANSACTION` e todos os comandos desejados;
- Após o término, verifique se ocorreu erros, se ocorreu execute o comando `ROLLBACK`, se tudo foi bem, execute o `COMMIT`.

Para mais informações sobre *transactions*, [leia a documentação do mysql sobre transaction](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx/)

Comment: Pode me ajudar com a syntax Ricardo?! ja pesquisei sobre, e mantém-se o error... Obrigado!

Comment: Fiz a edição como você pediu ricardo, obrigado pela atenção, aguardo sua resposta

Comment: agora ficou melhor :)  adicionei mais informação na resposta

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo pela ajuda ! Consegui entender e executar, vi alguns outros exemplos que também me deram uma luz, obrigado pela paciencia e atenção ! Grande abraço